# angular http not working under very specific conditions

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a project using angular.
in this project i have created a dropdown directive.
this directive does a get request to fill the dropdown menu

now some pages have multiple dropdowns and under a few very specific circumstances the http request wil not respond to the answer from the server (altough it says it sent it)

1. the request wasn't done on initial load but initiated by reloading it using angular routing
2. the dropdown information references it's own id(a bit project specific)
3. only the first directive doesnt work subsequent dropdown directives do work

this is the directive

```
app.directive('dropdown', function($http){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        templateUrl:'/templates/dropdown.html',
        scope:{
            selectedid:'=',
            objectdefinition:'='
        },
        link:function(scope){
            scope.visible = false;

            $http.get("/api/" + scope.objectdefinition.key)
            .then(function(res) {
                scope.data = res.data
            },function(){

            });

            scope.$watch('selectedid',function(newVal){
                if(newVal != null){
                    console.log('made')
                    $http.get("/api/" + scope.objectdefinition.key + '/' + scope.selectedid)
                    .then(function(res) {
                        console.log('received')
                        scope.selectedObject = res.data;
                    },function(){

                    });
                }
            })

            scope.select = function(item){
                scope.visible = false;
                scope.selectedObject = item
                scope.selectedid = item._id
            }

        }
    }
});
```

and this is it being called in the view

```
.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2
    form
        .form-group
            button.btn.btn-success(ng-click='save()') Save
            a.btn.btn-danger(href='/{{object}}') Cancel
        .form-group(ng-repeat='attribute in current.attributes' ng-switch="attribute.type")
            label {{attribute.name}}
            div(ng-if='!attribute.array')            
                input.form-control(ng-switch-when='text' placeholder='{{attribute.name}}' ng-model='$parent.$parent.$parent.data[attribute.name]') 
                datetimepicker(ng-switch-when='date' placeholder='{{attribute.name}}' model='$parent.$parent.$parent.data[attribute.name]')
           ---->dropdown(ng-switch-when='object' selectedid='$parent.$parent.$parent.data[attribute.name]' objectdefinition='definition[attribute.objectType]' )
                button.btn.btn-default(ng-switch-when='boolean' ng-model='$parent.$parent.$parent.data[attribute.name]' bs-checkbox)

                input.form-control(ng-switch-default placeholder='{{attribute.name}}' ng-model='$parent.$parent.$parent.data[attribute.name]') 
            div.well(ng-if='attribute.array' )
                .panel.panel-default(style='display:inline-block; margin-right: 10px' ng-repeat='entry in $parent.$parent.data[attribute.name] track by $index')
                    .panel-body
                        input( ng-model='entry').form-control
```

and here is a picture of the problem
initial load everything works fine notive 2 request were made each for 1 dropdown
[initial load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmEGH.png)

somehow doesnt work because only 1 http call returned
[navigated away and back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXWO4.png)

I realize that this is a very specific question and there is a bit more to the project than just these lines of code but I was really hoping that someone else before has walked against this weird behaviour of $http(because i think the problem has something to with that)

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be something wrong with angular's http service

however this does seem to work but i dont know why angular's version doesnt work

```
$.get("/api/" + scope.objectdefinition.key + '/' + scope.selectedid,function(res) {
                        scope.selectedObject = res;
                        scope.$apply();
                    });
```